# Parity Mnemonic or Keyfile not compatible with MEW?

Tags: parity, myetherwallet

I'm on a new computer and I have 2 ETH addresses I created on parity in december 2017 and february 2018. Now I thought I followed the plan on what to do to secure the addresses but when I enter the 12 words Mnemonic in MEW and give the password, it claims the Mnemonic isn't correct. "Invalid Mnemonic".

Is it incompatible?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

The old Parity phrases don't use the [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) standard, used by many wallets, so it's not compatible. You can import your Parity phrase into the [Parity Signer](https://www.parity.io/signer/) app and use [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com) in order to move your funds to a different address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try that. I already feared I have to wait until Parity synced. It ran the whole night and only became way slower with an outlook for weeks to wait. :D
Hope it works out.

Comment: I could test the two apps now. Works great. Best working ETH wallet yet. :D

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say thank you for your help! Tried the above and want to give a more detailed description of the answer above.

A couple of years ago I wasn't really aware of what I was doing and created an address using Parity. In the meantime Parity is kinda obsolete and wanted to migrate my crypto funds to another address.

So, I installed Parity Signer(was the only app that recognized the reset phrase/mnemonic) and could access my address. Afterwards used MyCrypto.com desktop app to send the funds to another address.

I found this step-by-step tutorial for newbies https://openethereum.wiki/Parity-Signer-Mobile-App-MyCrypto-tutorial/ .

Hope it helps!